# stm32f3 discovery gcc-arm eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gcc, stm32, stm32f4discovery

Does anyone have a working open source environment for the STM32 F3 discovery board? Does anyone have a tutorial that can be easily ported from the STM32 F4/ F0 to the F3 discovery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created a tutorial with free tools(Eclipse, OpenOCD and Codesourcery toolchain).
http://www.engineering-diy.blogspot.ro/2012/11/stm32f3-discovery-eclipse-openocd.html

Regards,
Andrei